# Facebook Connect error: can't post to wall in iPhone

Tags: iphone

My app just suddenly can't post to wall, I've tried to change my api key and secret key but still there was no success of posting my message, and it leaves my app hanging with the activity indicator loading...Can anyone please suggest what needs to be done? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to latest iOs FbConnect SDK