# FBConnect: can't post to wall

Tags: iphone, sdk, facebook, fbconnect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Connect error: can't post to wall in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337697/facebook-connect-error-cant-post-to-wall-in-iphone)

I had a problem with my app using FBConnect, the last time I was working with it, it works fine, but now, it can't post data from my webserver to my facebook wall. I tried to replace the api key and secret key but still there was no success. Do I need to update my iOs FBConnect SDK?

any suggestion please? 
thanks

Comment: Please do not repost questions; if you have anything new to add to your existing question, use the edit link beneath its text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some time ago they changed something in there logic, and some not-official APIs stoped working. BUT, they posted a **very** good tutorial about how to use new one. highly recommend it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/